# GWT 2.6 with GXT-3.0.1 error in compile

Tags: gwt, gxt

since the 2.6.0 release of GWT which dropped support of ie6 browser my current project which also uses GXT is failing to compile with the following error:

```
Loading inherited module 'com.sencha.gxt.ui.GXT'
        Loading inherited module 'com.sencha.gxt.data.Data'
           Loading inherited module 'com.sencha.gxt.core.Core'
              [ERROR] The value ie6 was not previously defined.
              [ERROR] Line 96: Unexpected exception while processing element 'set-property'
```

i tried to set 
`<set-property name="gxt.user.agent" value="safari3, safari4, safari5, chrome, air, gecko1_8, gecko1_9"/>` and the `<extend-property name="user.agent" ....../>`
but without any success. Are there any workarounds on this?

Comment: a beta jar release and good workaround are available: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22156317/1915920

Answer (score 8, accepted):

GWT 2.6.0 has several breaking changes over GWT 2.4.0 and 2.5.1 - these don't affect all libraries, but they do affect both GXT 2 and 3. Code changes in GWT 2.6.0 that break libraries like GXT include:

- Changing permutations (`ie6` and `opera` are gone, `ie10` was added, note that newer versions of opera are webkit based and do not need their own permutation)
- Element added new final methods hasClassName and toggleClassName that can't compiled with XElement methods of the same name
- String utils methods removed, switched to newer version of Guava (which now uses those methods)

---

Saw an upvote, so I know this is still getting readers months later, so editing this to point out that GXT 3.1.0 is in maven central and supports GWT 2.6.0, 2.6.1, and as of Friday anyway, supports GWT 2.7.0-SNAPSHOT. I can't promise it is totally future-proof, but as long no public methods in GWT change, it isn't likely to break again in the GWT 2.7 series.

Comment: thank you thank you. man I spent a lot of time trying to figure out why I was getting this error!

Comment: any solutions for the problem ??

Comment: The problem is that GWT 2.6 and GWT 2.4-2.5 aren't compatible. The solution is to release a new version of GXT that isn't compatible with GWT 2.4/2.5 or earlier versions of GXT. We're working on it, but GWT 2.6 was released about 6 wks late of planned, and we aren't ready right away. Stay tuned, will be available soon.