# ie6 wast not previously defined error in GWT 2.6.0/GXT2.5.1

Tags: gwt, gxt

I got the following error when compiling the code with GWT 2.6.0 and GXT 2.5.1.

```
Loading inherited module 'com.sencha.gxt.ui.GXT'L
    Loading inherited module 'com.sencha.gxt.data.Data'
        Loading inherited module 'com.sencha.gxt.core.Core'
            [ERROR] The value ie6 was not previously defined.
            [ERROR] Line 96: Unexpected exception while processing element 'set-property'
```

Even though we don't specify ie6 in gxt.user.agent, we still get the error: "[ERROR] The value ie6 was not previously defined." 
Why does GXT still try to set ie6 despite we don't set it in gxt.user.agent?

Does anyone know when Sencha will release a new GXT version that resolve this problem?

Answer (score 5):

They released a beta already: https://www.sencha.com/blog/announcing-gxt-3.1-beta/

…or you could re-enable the `ie6` permutation:

```
<extend-property name="user.agent" value="ie6" />
```

Comment: the extend-property did not working placing it before or after the gxt inherit :-/ but the jar works :-)

Comment: 3.1.0 is out.  Now you just need to update to the latest version of Sencha GXT. http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sencha.gxt/gxt

Comment: They also just released GXT 2.3.1a compatible with GWT 2.6.1 if you can't update to 3.x: https://plus.google.com/+BrandonDonnelson/posts/VuVCLuabcba

Answer (score 2):

Just to clarify 2 points,

1. If using GXT-3.0.1 or earlier  =>  It is only compatible with GWT-2.5.1 (or earlier).
2. If using GXT-3.1.0_Beta  =>  It is only compatible with GWT-2.6.0 (or later).

Otherwise various errors will be caused during compilation/runtime.