# ie6 wast not previously defined error in GWT 2.6.0/GXT2.3.1a

Tags: gwt, gxt

We are in the process of migrating from GXT 2.3.1 and GWT 2.5.0 to GWT 2.6, we found that there is a compatible version with GWT 2.6 for GXT this version is GXT 2.3.1a, updating the maven dependencies to for GXT to 2.3.1a work perfectly.

But know we are trying to update GWT to 2.6 and when we compile we receive the following error:

```
[INFO] Loading inherited module 'com.#####.####.login.Login'
[INFO]    Loading inherited module 'com.sencha.gxt.ui.GXT'
[INFO]       Loading inherited module 'com.sencha.gxt.data.Data'
[INFO]          Loading inherited module 'com.sencha.gxt.core.Core'
[INFO]             [ERROR] The value ie6 was not previously defined.
[INFO]             [ERROR] Line 96: Unexpected exception while processing element 'set-property'
```

I've search for this error and found this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22155432/ie6-wast-not-previously-defined-error-in-gwt-2-6-0-gxt2-5-1) it look very similar but the way they suggest to fix it doesn't work for me. So either I'm doing something wrong or is a different issue.

Can someone explain where do you need to put the:

```
<extend-property name="user.agent" value="ie6" />
```

Comment: You need to use GXT 3.1.x in order to make it work. GWT 2.6.0 is not compatible with earlier versions of gxt. There is no backward compatibility since GWT 2.6 removes `com.google.gwt.user.client.Element` (which has long been deprecated). But, I guess, your problem is due to the fact it removes also the compilation permutation for ie6.

Comment: @RadASM GWT 2.6 works fine with GXT 2.3.1a, that was the point of the 2.3.1a release. GWT 2.6 does _not_ remove user.client.Element, it merely deprecates it (officially, with an annotation, instead of just saying "don't use this"), to be removed in the following release.

Answer (score 2):

```
<extend-property name="user.agent" value="ie6" />
```

Will go in your gwt.xml file. I dont think its too fussy where. After the GWT inherits should be ok.

However, umm....not sure if GWT even supports IE6 anymore, even as an optional permutation. It might make things worse.
I had to add Opera support awhile back and it worked. But even pre-blink Operas are quite a bit more standards supporting then ie6 was.

```
 <extend-property name="user.agent" values="opera" />
```

If you want to do a quick test of a browser without compiling everything else you can manually set all the browsers you want to support with set:

```
 <set-property name="user.agent" value="ie8,ie9,opera,gecko1_8,safari" />
```

Its been a good few years since I touched this stuff though, so I confess I am not 100% sure its its the correct way, or will work on newer GWT versions.

Comment: Add ie10 to the last statement, and you've got all browsers GWT 2.6 knows how to support, deprecated or otherwise.